# How one can create users field like "Assigned To" field in vtigercrm?

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I have a module ABC in that i need to create another users picklist irrespective of "Assigned To" like already there for every module. I tried to create that by copying existed field for "Assigned To" in **vtiger_field** table. But it is not working for me nothing new happens in module ABC.

```
tabid : ABD(tabid)
columname : doneby
tablename : vtiger_crmentity
generatedtype : 1
uitype : 53
fieldname : doneby
fieldlabel : Inspected By
readonly : 1
presence : 2
maximumlength : 100
block : <confused>(Need clarification)
typeofdata : V~M
summaryfield : 1
```

i really confused with block and `typeofdata` field.

Can anybody help me to get users list field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create it by modifying tablename with vtiger_abc and block is likely to be same as where you expected follow the already existed block which you identify in vtiger_field previous colums in the same table.

More ever you need to create the same name field in vtiger_abc table also which must be varchar(size).

Change the typeofdata with `V~0` this is for optional. Because "Assigned To" entity field will have mandatory so if you really need it as mandatory then let it be.

```
update these two fields.
tablename : vtiger_abc
block : <update with existing block of same table field>
```